# How to set an array in Jtextfield using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a small application . In this application I have 5 words. I have one JtextField and JButton.The name of JtextField is set as name1 and JButton name set as next.

I want to set a default word  in name1 from 1st word of string array ( *from this code I am giving one example is need to see in JtextField is as **"me"***) when application run I want to see the word from String array before the the next button click.  how I can set the data to name1?

code is as follows:

```
String s[]={"me","and","my","friends","are"};
    int i=0; 
    private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        if(i>=s.length)
       i=0;
      name1.setText(s[i]);
      i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the method after you created your fields with null as argument as you don't use the argument.

```
nextActionPerformed(null);
```

This will simulate that the button is pressed when the program starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button which has action Listener attached. If not then it should be something like below:

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
 nextActionPerformed(e);
 // Or move your code here from nextActionPerformed(e)
}
});
//And you can also initialize your text filed with first value of array:
textField.setText(s[0]);
```